# High Speed Collisions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, physics, rigid-bodies

I am currently writing a C# simulation of a boat with a number of speeds. With my **rigidbody** and **colliders**, it works just fine at low speeds, but once the boat goes to the higher speeds, it starts going straight through the other **colliders**.

I have tried:

- changing the physics rules
- editing the rigid body rules
- and even using the [DontGoThroughThings](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/DontGoThroughThings) code

The new code has somewhat increased the speed the boat can collide at, but not enough for the simulation.

Comment: have you tried reducing the physic time step?

Comment: And what is the Collision Detection set to in your Rigidbody? And what is your boat colliding with?

Comment: @Heisenbug No, how do I do that?

Comment: @Bart Collision Detection is Continous Dynamic, & Interpolate is set to none

Comment: ProjectSettings->Time->Fixed TimeStep: be careful that reducing it will inpact cpu performances.

Comment: If you can somehow cheat with your colliders (i.e. make them a bit bigger) that might be an alternative option.

Comment: As well as setting `Collision Detection` to `Continuous Dynamic` on your fast moving objects, I believe you also need to set it to `Continuous` on the other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I only needed to got to
**ProjectSettings -> Time -> Fixed TimeStep**
There you just need to raise the number by a little bit. Be careful though, if you raise the value too much it will freeze the program.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but, if you are using something to do with transform, then try using `AddForce` on your rigidbody, it works better with collisions. Here is a link to the docs, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html